# Alignment Issue in telerik editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-editor

I am using telerik editor(in asp.net), I am trying to write some content in that, some words or content are place on right hand side using tab key (i.e 4 time  ).
At design time it display properly but when I print that document the right hand side words goes to  the next line or some time it comes in middle of the page.
how I can solve this alignment problem??
1.before print(i.e design time in editor)
[image]
1.after print(i.e A4 page image after print)
[image]
thank you.

Comment: You may want to post relevant code for more help. Off the top of my head, it sounds like you may need a dedicated print CSS style sheet to solve this problem, since it only exists when you print.

Comment: Hi David,
Thank you for response, please check updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have two options as I see it:*

1. Define your own `Print.css` file and follow the instructions on this [Telerik documentation page](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-printing-content-with-styles.html) to ensure the print `CSS` is used. This will ensure printing is consistent and any stripping of CSS done by the browser is avoided.
2. Generate a `PDF` from the Telerik editor, and print the `PDF`. See [this Telerik documentation page with demo code](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx) for more details on how to generate a PDF from the Telerik ASP.net RadEditor control.